# trying to insert variable on submit with new message

Tags: php, pdo

anyone have any idea what im doing wrong with my code below? i got it to grab the variable and show the subject, message and date fine, but what i'm trying to do is get it to add the subject from the variable (a new custom message from a textarea) and date from the variable to the database.

```
    <?php
require("db.php");

$query_params = array(
  ':id' => $_GET['id'],
  ':username' => $_SESSION['user']['username']
);
$query = "SELECT id, subject, message, date FROM tickets
              WHERE username = :username And id= :id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
  $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch($result)) {
    echo $row['subject'];
    echo $row['message'];
    echo $row['date'];

    PROBLEMS WITH THE CODE BELOW>>>>

if(!empty($_POST))
{
if(empty($_POST['message']))
{
$error="Please enter a Message.";
}
else
{
$query = "
INSERT INTO supporttickets (
username,
subject,
message,
date
) VALUES (
:username,
:subject,
:message,
date
)
";
$query_params = array(
':username' => $_SESSION['user']['username'],
':subject' => $_POST['subject'],
':date' => $_POST['date'],
':message' => $_POST['message']
);
   $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
   $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
  }
 }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" name="form">
<textarea name="message" cols="71" rows="9" id="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the params. It should match on how you construct your INSERT query. I switched message and date.

```
$query_params = array(
':username' => $_SESSION['user']['username'],
':subject' => $_POST['subject'],
':message' => $_POST['message'],
':date' => $_POST['date']
);
```

Comment: How about your values? you have no : on before date params VALUES (
:username,
:subject,
:message,
:date
)

Comment: hi i've also tried that with no luck, i have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`date` is a MySQL keyword and you forget to put `:date` as well. So it should be

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO supporttickets (
   username,
   subject,
   message,
   `date`
) VALUES (
   :username,
   :subject,
   :message,
   :date
)";
```